# Create a subfolder using value as name

Tags: c#, winforms, path, subdirectory

I'm using the next code to create a folder in my project path

```
 string projectPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
 string folderName = Path.Combine(projectPath, "images");
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
```

It create a folder `image` ... now i want to create a sub folder take its name from a text box value in my form .. and every time the value changed then a new sub folder created with the new value as name

for example if my form has a text box with a value `56` then i want to create a folder `image` inside it a sub folder called `56` so the path will be `...\image\56`

if the value changed to `48` then create new folder with sub folder `...\image\48` ... etc

Comment: So add `myTextBox.Text` as another parameter in `Path.Combine`.

Comment: So what issue you are facing in reusing current code with combining proper path with `images` and the value from the textbox? Did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine names with your view value, and test if the new folder already exists before creating it :

```
var myValueFromView = "56";
string projectPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
string folderName = Path.Combine(projectPath, "images", myValueFromView);
if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderName))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
```